# I want to enter data from a GridView into a Word document and have it downloaded from client

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-word

```
var gd = new GridView
{
    DataSource = li,
    AutoGenerateColumns = true,
};

gd.DataBind();

if (gd.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "List" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".doc");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());

    var oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    var oHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);

    gd.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

ERROR (lines wrapped):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
The message received from the server could not be parsed.' when calling method:
[nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]
[Break On This Error]   

Filtered chrome url chrome://firebug/content/net/spy.js

spy.js (line 807)
<System>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
```

Comment: What about: 

`Response.Clear();// make this response a file download
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
// set a default filename for the download
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachmentName); 
// set the length of the download
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString()); 
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
Response.End();`

I've copied this from a working example (sorry I can't find how to insert line breaks..)

Comment: @Alex: please add this as an answer and accept it. I'll upvote if you also add some context: what did the page look like that  you called this code from?

Comment: Solved! In aspx page I added trigger for button Export: </ContentTemplate> <Triggers> <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" /> </Triggers> </asp:UpdatePanel>